# How to download pipeline artifacts from azure pipeline to local using powershell?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to download artifacts from azure pipeline on my local machine. Can anyone help in doing this using powershell script?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is my workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I used your Suggested method to convert my PAT token to Base64 then i used that in creating Authorization header which is used in Invoke-Restmethod. Thanks for helping I got my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$token = "xxx"
    
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/builds/{BuildID}/artifacts?artifactName={ArtifactName}&api-version=6.1-preview.5&%24format=zip"
    
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
    
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/zip -OutFile "{SomePath}\Response.zip"
```

Note: Add `&%24format=zip` after the url and set `-ContentType application/zip -OutFile "{SomePath}\Response.zip"`

You need to replace `token(PAT),OrgName,ProjectName,BuildID,ArtifactName` with your own values. And choose one existing path to save the response, such as `C:\pub\Response.zip`. I have existing path `C:\pub`, after running the PS script I can get one created `Response.zip` which contains the artifact I need.

In addition , you can also try to download the build artifact through c# code. For details,please refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62911393/azure-devops-fail-to-get-artifact-content-zip-with-tfs-client-lib/62930746#62930746).

```
static readonly string TFUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/OrgName/";
static readonly string UserPAT = "PAT";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        int buildId = xx; // update to an existing build definition id
        string artifactName = "drop"; //default artifact name
    //  string project = "projectName";
        ConnectWithPAT(TFUrl, UserPAT);

        Stream zipStream = BuildClient.GetArtifactContentZipAsync(buildId, artifactName).Result; //get content
        using (FileStream zipFile = new FileStream(@"C:\MySite\test.zip", FileMode.Create))
            zipStream.CopyTo(zipFile);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        if (ex.InnerException != null) Console.WriteLine("Detailed Info: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Stack:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: At one go your code worked for PowerShell... Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have `%24` in your URL? Should it not be `&api-version=6.1-preview.5&format=zip`?

Answer (score 7):

The solutions provided above do not or no longer work - the API seems to have changed. If you use the solutions you get HTML content asking you to sign in.

The new API returns JSON with a downloadUrl:

```json
{
  "id": 105284,
  "name": "Artifact",
  "resource": {
    ...
    "downloadUrl": "https://artprodsu6weu.artifacts.visualstudio.com/....."        
  }
}
```

So here is some code which works fine:

```
$BuildId = "154782"
$ArtifactName = "Artifact"
$OutFile = "Artifact.zip"
$OrgName="myorg"
$ProjectName="myproject"

$PAT = "**************"
    
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$($OrgName)/$($ProjectName)/_apis/build/builds/$($BuildID)/artifacts?artifactName=$($ArtifactName)&api-version=&format=zip"
    
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
    
# Get the download URL
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"}
$downloadUrl = $response.resource.downloadUrl

# Download the artifact
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -OutFile $OutFile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Artifacts Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1):

```
$token = "Your PAT"

# Create Authorization header
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $token"}

# Create Web client - used to downlaod files
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", $headers["Authorization"])

            # Get Build artifact details
            $buildId = "the artifats build id"
            $artifactsUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/artifacts?api-version=4.1"
            $buildArtifacts = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $headers -Uri $artifactsUrl

            foreach($buildArtifact in $buildArtifacts.value){
                # Download build artifacts - ZIP files
                $url = $buildArtifact.resource.downloadUrl
                $output = Join-Path $artifactsDir "$($buildArtifact.name).zip"
                $wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
            }

$wc.Dispose()
```

Comment: can you try to debug the lines with `Write-Host` and check which line doesn't work?

Comment: did you replace the values in `{organization}` & `{project}` with your project details and put value in `$buildId`?

Comment: i am running with all required changes